# While loop inside for loop is not changing value of i of for loop in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, python-3.6

Here is my code

```
A = [0,0,-1,0]
for i in range(len(A)):
    while (i<len(A)) and (A[i] >=0):
        print(i, A[i]) 
        i=i+1
```

when I am executing this code in python 3.x my output is

```
Output

0 0
1 0
1 0
3 0
```

My question is :
When while loop exits for the first time value of  `i` becomes `2` since `A[2] < 0`

But after that when it goes to parent for loop then why value of `i` again becomes `1`?

Because after that in 3rd line of output it prints `1 0` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python `for` loops are not like C `for` loops; the iteration value is *replaced* on each loop, discarding any changes made inside the loop. No matter what you do to `i` inside the `for` loop, when the `for` loop loops, you pull the next value from the iterator, so `i` will always progress through all the values in the `range` one at a time.

Comment: Note: There *are* some ways to mess with this (involving storing the iterator to a variable outside the loop, and manually advancing it so the iterator being processed by `for` is itself modified, but when you're in a situation that complex, it's usually better to just simulate a C-style `for` loop with a `while`.

Answer (score 2):

The 'for' statement does not work like it might in C. The i variable gets reassigned each iteration.

You can think of 'for i in x' as being more like:  while x has more values, set i to the next value from x.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens after the while loop exits. i is set to the next value in `range(len(A))` which is 1 for the next iteration of the for loop.

You can fix this by initializing i and removing the for loop

```
A = [0,0,-1,0]
i=0
while (i<len(A)) and (A[i] >=0):
   print(i, A[i]) 
   i=i+1
```

Or using the `break` command

```
A = [0,0,-1,0]
for i in range(len(A)):
    if(A[i]<0):
        break
    print(i, A[i])
```

Answer (score -2):

Try running the code in any Python debugger and you'll see it all at once.
The code works correctly.
If you need a specific result, ask, I will help you.